# Prevent Screen Saver Whilst Screen Sharing in Google Meet

Tags: macos, google-chrome, screensaver, brave, google-meet

When in a meeting with Google Meet the screensaver will activate if Google Meet doesn't run in the foreground or active browser window. But when sharing the screen, one has always another screen/tab in the foreground ‍♂️

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Using MacOS 13.3.1
Brave Version 1.51.118 Chromium: 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (arm64)
<- happens also with Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Hot Corners

Set one corner to Disable Screen Saver, then whenever you're not active, just remember to push your cursor into this corner. This will also prevent Sleep as a consequence of not allowing screen saver.

[image]